# Extract part of a 3 D dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3d dataframe. looks like this:

```
     d1        d2            d3
   A B C D...   A B C D...   A B C D..
0  
1
2
```

How could I extract only column  A & B from every d1,d2.....? I desire to take the dataframe like this:

```
    d1    d2    d3
  A  B   A  B   A  B
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html#pandas-index-isin) on the level 1 values of columns then select with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
filtered_df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['A', 'B'], level=1)]
```

`filtered_df`:

```
   d1      d2    
    A   B   A   B
0   1   2   5   6
1   9  10  13  14
2  17  18  21  22
```

---

Sample Data Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(1, 25).reshape((-1, 8)),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((['d1', 'd2'], list('ABCD')))
)
```

```
   d1              d2            
    A   B   C   D   A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
2  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
```